# Images in Media Library improperly duplicated via Product Image URL field in API

Tags: wordpress, image, woocommerce, salesforce

I have a Woo store with an API integration from Salesforce.

Each time a product is saved in Salesforce, the data from all connected fields pushes over to Woo and overwrites the data in Woo.

The Product Image is being populated with a full URL from a Salesforce field, like this:

```
http://thecrucible.org/wp-content/uploads/crucible-test-image.jpg
```

Each time the field pushes over to Woo, the image is duplicated in the Media Library, like this:

```
http://thecrucible.org/wp-content/uploads/crucible-test-image-2.jpg
http://thecrucible.org/wp-content/uploads/crucible-test-image-3.jpg
http://thecrucible.org/wp-content/uploads/crucible-test-image-4.jpg
```

And so on..

The Product always uses the latest version of the duplicated image.

Is this a core function of Woo, to duplicate an image when its URL is re-populated via an API integration? I don't imagine I would want to try to "turn off" that feature. Or maybe it's actually WP core function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After speaking to an engineer at WooCommerce.com, they confirmed that if I create/update the image via the API using the "id" field rather than the "src" field, the image duplication problem will go away because WordPress will correctly recognize the image as an existing image in the Media Library.

Comment: Curious to know, does this mean updating the image based on the ID of the existing image as its which is to be extracted prior to doing an update, or is it if you create / update a product, populating the ID with the URL of the image instead?

Comment: Perfect timing, as I just fixed this recently and can answer this for you. The images are already existent in the Media Library, and the image ID is placed in a field in Salesforce, which then syncs the ID (just the numeric portion) over via the Woo API field called simple "id" - in the Product - Images Properties section of the API. https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#product-properties  . We had previously synced the full URL of the image over, using the "src" field, which triggers WP into creating a duplicate image.

Comment: @Melodist so you basically need to check if the image is there with a GET request on the product and then use the id of the images whose url matches the list of urls to be synced.

Comment: @beppe9000 That's horribad.

Comment: when I post like this:
"images":[ { "id": "https://example.com/wp-content....jpg"}]
I get response:
'message': 'images[0][id] is not type integer'

Comment: @Melodist How can I do that? How to use id instead of src?